# Programmatic UIControl as subview of IB UIView doesn't get interaction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uicontrol

I'm having a bit of trouble with the right parts of the view hierarchy in my iPhone app getting the touch events they should be. The code is all Swift in iOS 11.

I have a UIControl subclass which overrides beginTracking() and endTracking(). Originally, I had programmatically created a UIView, and then added an instance of my UIControl subclass as a subview. The code basically boiled down to:

```
myView = UIView()
view.addSubview(myView)
// add autolayout constraints for the view
myControl = TheControl(frame: theFrame)
myView.addSubview(myControl)
// add autolayout constraints for the control
```

This worked fine, but I wanted to have myView in Interface Builder to make autolayout a bit easier. So I got rid of the 'myView=UIView()' and 'view.addSubview(myView)' lines, created the view in IB, and connected it to an outlet in the view controller. The rest of the code stayed the same. So I programmatically create myControl, and add it as a subview of myView. Now that I have done this, myControl no longer receives touch events.

I can't figure out what is happening differently by doing this in Interface Builder vs. in code. I have toggled on and off "User Interaction Enabled" on myView in IB, and as far as I can tell it doesn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Then give it UITapGestureRecognizer or equivalent?  Nobody know what TheControl is.

Comment: Try bringing the subview to front, if you haven't try that